# ArcMap Extension Creating a Shapefile with too many columns result in a Memory Error

Tags: c#, arcgis, shapefile, arcmap

I am creating an ESRI ArcMap 10.2 extension in VS2012 C#.  I keep running into an issue where when I create a shapefile with a good number of columns I get the error:

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

when actually running the Create Feature method on the feature workspace.  Here is the code excerpt:

```
public bool LoadData(DataQueryResult QueryResult, string ColumnX, string ColumnY)
{
    bool loaded = true;
    DataTable Data = QueryResult.ResultsTable;

    try
    {
        using (ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.ComReleaser ComReleaser = new ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.ComReleaser())
        {
            //Create the field collection for editing
            IFields Fields = new FieldsClass();
            ComReleaser.ManageLifetime(Fields);
            IFieldsEdit FieldsEdit = (IFieldsEdit)Fields;

            //Create the geometry field
            IGeometryDef GeomDef = new GeometryDef();
            IGeometryDefEdit GeomDefEdit = (IGeometryDefEdit)GeomDef;
            GeomDefEdit.GeometryType_2 = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPoint;

            IField GeomField = new FieldClass();
            IFieldEdit GeomFieldEdit = (IFieldEdit)GeomField;
            GeomFieldEdit.Name_2 = ShapeFieldName;
            GeomFieldEdit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeGeometry;
            GeomFieldEdit.GeometryDef_2 = GeomDef;
            GeomDefEdit.SpatialReference_2 = new UnknownCoordinateSystemClass();;

            FieldsEdit.AddField(GeomField);

            //Create the OID filed
            IField OidField = new FieldClass();
            IFieldEdit OidFieldEdit = (IFieldEdit)OidField;
            OidFieldEdit.Name_2 = "OID";
            OidFieldEdit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeOID;
            FieldsEdit.AddField(OidField);

            //Add a field for each column
            foreach (DataColumn col in Data.Columns)
            {
                IField2 field = new FieldClass();
                IFieldEdit fieldedit = (IFieldEdit)field;
                fieldedit.Name_2 = col.ColumnName;
                bool AddField = false;

                if (col.DataType.IsIn(typeof(Int64), typeof(Int32)))
                {
                    //Best we can do is 32 bit in a shapefile
                    fieldedit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeInteger;
                    AddField = true;
                }
                else if (col.DataType == typeof(Int16))
                {
                    fieldedit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeSmallInteger;
                    AddField = true;
                }
                else if (col.DataType == typeof(Single))
                {
                    fieldedit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeSingle;
                    AddField = true;
                }
                else if (col.DataType == typeof(double))
                {
                    fieldedit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeDouble;
                    AddField = true;
                }
                else if (col.DataType == typeof(string))
                {
                    fieldedit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeString;
                    //Here is where I get "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." 
                    //The higher the number of fields the fewer "runs" of this method needed to hit the error.
                    //At 150 it is hit right away but if it is at, say, 50 it can run many times.
                    if (Fields.FieldCount < 150) 
                        AddField = true;
                    else
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(field.Name + "; ");
                }
                else if (col.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    fieldedit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeDate;
                    AddField = true;
                }
                else if (col.DataType == typeof(bool))
                {
                    fieldedit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeString;
                    AddField = true;
                }

                if (AddField)
                    FieldsEdit.AddField(field);

            }

            //FilePath is the ArcMap temp folder generated for the session so something like "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\arc1097\\"
            IWorkspaceFactory WorkspaceFactory = new ShapefileWorkspaceFactoryClass();
            IFeatureWorkspace FeatureWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)WorkspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(FilePath, hWnd);
            ComReleaser.ManageLifetime(WorkspaceFactory);

            //FileName is a class memeber which might be something like "o2zkdrnv.shp" which is randomly generated
            FeatureClass = FeatureWorkspace.CreateFeatureClass(FileName, Fields, null, null, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, ShapeFieldName, "");  //<-- THE ERROR OCCURS HERE
            ComReleaser.ManageLifetime(FeatureClass);
        }
    }
}
```

So I can only assume it is some sort of memory error.  The more columns I allow (the line with "< 150") the few number of times I can repeat the run before hitting the error.  Seems around 65 is the threshold where I start to see it right away.  Below that, I can run it, say, 5-6 times before hitting it but that seems very inconsistent.  And it seems to happen sooner if I stop debugging VS and restart the project.  I added the ComReleaser thinking it might help (even thought it is not technically part of the ArcMap namespace) but it made no difference.

The datatable being passed contains the following list of fields:

```
RecordID,SiteID,SiteName,SiteType,LocID,LocName,LocType,LocX,LocY,LocZ,LocLong,LocLat,LocTop,LocBot,LocGroup,SampID,SampName,SampDate,SampDate2,SampTime,SampTime2,SampType,SampGroup,SampMatrix,SampTop,cSampTop,SampBot,cSampBot,SampElev,cSampElev,SampUnit,AnalyteID,Analyte,Result,cResult,Flag,Unit,DetectLim,cDetectLim,IsDetect,IsTIC,IsReject,Method,Category,LabID,Comment,Source,RegName01,RegValue01,RegAbove01,RegName02,RegValue02,RegAbove02,RegName03,RegValue03,RegAbove03,RegName04,RegValue04,RegAbove04,RegName05,RegValue05,RegAbove05,RegName06,RegValue06,RegAbove06,RegName07,RegValue07,RegAbove07,RegName08,RegValue08,RegAbove08,RegName09,RegValue09,RegAbove09,RegName10,RegValue10,RegAbove10,RegName11,RegValue11,RegAbove11,RegName12,RegValue12,RegAbove12,RegName13,RegValue13,RegAbove13,RegName14,RegValue14,RegAbove14,RegName15,RegValue15,RegAbove15,RegName16,RegValue16,RegAbove16,RegName17,RegValue17,RegAbove17,RegName18,RegValue18,RegAbove18,RegName19,RegValue19,RegAbove19,RegName20,RegValue20,RegAbove20,RegName21,RegValue21,RegAbove21,RegName22,RegValue22,RegAbove22,RegName23,RegValue23,RegAbove23,RegName24,RegValue24,RegAbove24,RegName25,RegValue25,RegAbove25,RegName26,RegValue26,RegAbove26,RegName27,RegValue27,RegAbove27,RegName28,RegValue28,RegAbove28,RegName29,RegValue29,RegAbove29,RegName30,RegValue30,RegAbove30
```

In theory, the content of the table should not matter since the only thing this method is drawing from it is the Columns collection.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You may check this out if you didn't: http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1170&t=205284

Comment: Thanks Ahmet.  I did read the article and tried a few of the suggestions but nothing seems to get it.  Chalk it up to another ESRI ArcObjects Quark I guess.  Have to try it a different way.